# Add video in HTML Popup on Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, video, html-popup

How to add Video in HTML Popup on ArcMap?
It said using xsl, but I just don't get it.. try to find tutorial but no luck

I use template codes :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
                </head>
                  <body>
                        <xsl:variable name="nameCol" select="FieldsDoc/Fields/Field/FieldName"/>
                              <table border="1" width="300" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tr bgcolor="#9cbce2">
                                          <xsl:if test="string-length($nameCol) != 0">
                                                <th width="50%" align="left">Field Name</th>
                                          </xsl:if>
                                          <th width="50%" align="left">Field Value</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <xsl:variable name="index" select="1"/>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="FieldsDoc/Fields/Field">
                                          <tr>
                                                <xsl:if test="(position() +1) mod 2">
                                                      <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">#D4e4f3</xsl:attribute>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="string-length($nameCol) != 0">
                                                      <td>
                                                      <xsl:value-of select="FieldName"/>
                                                      </td>
                                                </xsl:if>
                                                <td>
                                                      <xsl:choose>
                                                            <xsl:when test="FieldName[starts-with(., 'VIDEO')]">
                                                                  <xsl:variable name="videoURL" select="FieldValue"/>
                                                                  <object width="425" height="355">
                                                                        <param name="movie" value="{$videoURL}"></param>
                                                                        <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
                                                                        <embed src="{$videoURL}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="425" height="355">
                                                                        </embed>
                                                                  </object>
                                                            </xsl:when>
                                                            <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., 'www.')]">
                                                                  <a target="_blank"><xsl:attribute name="href">http://<xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                                                                  </xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                                                                  </a>
                                                            </xsl:when>
                                                            <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., 'http:')]">
                                                                  <a target="_blank"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                                                                  </xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                                                                  </a>  
                                                            </xsl:when>
                                                            <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., 'https:')]">
                                                                  <a target="_blank"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                                                                  </xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                                                                  </a>  
                                                            </xsl:when>
                                                            <xsl:when test="FieldValue[starts-with(., '\\')]">
                                                                  <a target="_blank"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                                                                  </xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                                                                  </a>  
                                                            </xsl:when>
                                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                  <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
                                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                                      </xsl:choose>
                                                </td>
                                          </tr>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                              </table>
                  </body>
            </html>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I create field called VIDEO and put sample video link such as "youtube.com/watch?v=lncOvjE4Fko", but when I click html popup nothing happened, it shows blank on video field. No tutorial or explanation further about adding video on HTML popup. (I already load the template from source given above, and mark "as a formated page based on an XSL Template")

Comment: The help says "For XSL template examples, refer to the HTMLPopup folder in the <install drive>:\Program Files\ArcGIS"

Comment: already tried but no luck, I create field called VIDEO and put sample video link such as "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lncOvjE4Fko", but when I click html popup nothing happened, it shows blank on video field. No tutorial or explanation further about adding video on HTML popup. (I already load the template from source given above, and mark "as a formated page based on an XSL Template")

Comment: edited question

Comment: can you show the code you added in your template?

Comment: sure, Actually I use Arcmap xsl template code from style "Embed Video"

Comment: Have you tried including the 'https ://www'. characters in your field value like: https ://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lncOvjE4Fko

Comment: yes i did, with and without it.

Comment: How is your URL formated in your field "VIDEO"?

Comment: Tested "youtube.com/watch?v=lncOvjE4Fko" and "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lncOvjE4Fko" , I use text type on my field.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://gisstudio.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/insert-an-image-into-your-html-pop-up-in-arcmap/

Comment: Yes, and it's only for image, not video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track with XLS, however when working with YouTube videos in HTML you need to use an `<iframe>` to display the video. The `<object>` and `<embed>` tag combination only works with video that have not been encode through YouTube or other video service, for example: mp4, Adobe Flash, or ogg.

1. Rewrite the URL from `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lncOvjE4Fko` to `https://www.youtube.com/embed/lncOvjE4Fko`This will allow the video to be played natively in the popup.
2. If you want the video to start automatically when the page loads add `?autoplay=1` to the end of the URL.
3. Replace the piece of code `<object width="425" height="355">...</object>` and put in the following:

`<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="**URL_GOES_HERE**" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

The width and height can be change to be what ever works best for your size of popup, if you use `100%` for both height and width it will auto size to window size.

Now when you open the popup the `<iframe>` will load the video and you should see the play button or if you added the  `?autoplay=1` parameter in the URL it will start playing automatically.

Here is your code with the field name **VIDEO** check in the XLS template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
 <xsl:variable name="ignoreFieldNames" select="'|OBJECTID|Shape|Shape_Length|Shape_Area|ATTACHMENTID|REL_OBJECTID|CONTENT_TYPE|ATT_NAME|DATA_SIZE|DATA|'"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
   </head>
   <body>
    <table>
     <tr style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:">
     </tr>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="FieldsDoc/Attachments" />
     <tr>
      <td>
       <table>
        <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="FieldsDoc/Fields/Field/FieldName">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="FieldsDoc/Fields/Field/FieldName[not(contains($ignoreFieldNames, concat(concat('|', text()), '|')))]/.." />
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="FieldsDoc/Fields/Field" />
         </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
       </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Field">
  <tr>

   <xsl:if test="FieldName">
    <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="FieldName"/>
    </td>
   </xsl:if>
   <td>
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="FieldName[starts-with(., 'VIDEO')]">
       <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" frameborder="0">
       <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
      </iframe>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have followed your direction, but still nothing happened, I dont know what's wrong with this thing..., please help me check it http://prntscr.com/c3ruqh

Comment: Please see edit above and give it a try.

Comment: as you see in http://prntscr.com/c49hf1 after I did based on your edited script nothing happened....

Comment: In ArcMap you do need to save the mxd and re-open to load any changes in the xls template, very annoying. When I open it the iframe is loading.

Comment: Yes, it's really annoying, really... and you deserve to have the bounty. If possible (if you don't mind) all my pictures are not displayed after I use xls, any clue?

Comment: Let me see... Did you want them embedded in the HTMl or links to open in another window?

Comment: Embeded in html popup.... please...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43788/discussion-between-daniel-walsh-and-rikudo-pain).

Answer (score -4):

Please show you code? 
When we help you quickly.

Are you replace to:

```
<td>    
    <xsl:if test="string-length($nameCol) != 0">
        <xsl:for-each select="FieldsDoc/Fields/Field">      
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="FieldName='VIDEO'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"  disable-output-escaping="yes" /> 
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>          
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</td>
```

Comment: Besides (but i don't sure) your ever line should start with 'VIDEO'

Comment: Is this an answer or follow-up questions for the OP?

Comment: I already show my code and what do you mean with ever line?